# WPF C# Diseño de una página con un arreglo de celdas en un DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, datagrid

Buenas tardes saludos a todos.

Estoy intentando de diseñar una página en **WPF C#** para que se vea de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Les aclaro que no soy experto programado en WPF pero intento hacer mi trabajo.

Lo he intentado haciendo uso de un **DataGrid**, también he probado con un **ListView** y por último lo intenté con un **ItemsControl**, en todas las opciones logro obtener una sola columna con el listado de libros de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero necesito que se muestren 4 columnas como en la primera imagen con los distintos libros ordenados de izquierda a derecha, como ve allí me repite las columnas no logro hacer que no se repitan por el "ItemsSource", la idea es usar una BD con N cantidad de libros.

Al final debería devolver el item seleccionado al darle click sobre algún libro deseado.

Les anexo parte de mi código para que me entiendan un poco mejor:

Esta es mi clase:

```
public class Product
{
    public string Image { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
    public double Stock { get; set; }
}
```

Acá está el ObservableCollection para el ItemsSource:

```
public vmProduct()
{
    Products = new ObservableCollection<Product>();
    Products.Add(new Product { Id = "001", Image = null, Name = "Visual C#", Price = 125, Stock = 10 }); 
    Products.Add(new Product { Id = "003", Image = null, Name = "Visual F#", Price = 115, Stock = 12 }); 
    Products.Add(new Product { Id = "005", Image = null, Name = "Visual Basic", Price = 105, Stock = 13 });
    Products.Add(new Product { Id = "002", Image = null, Name = "XAML", Price = 155, Stock = 11 });
    Products.Add(new Product { Id = "004", Image = null, Name = "PHP", Price = 145, Stock = 14 });
    Products.Add(new Product { Id = "006", Image = null, Name = "Node Js", Price = 135, Stock = 16 });
}
```

Y el código XAML:

```
<Grid DataContext="{StaticResource SourceProduct}">
    <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Products}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Margin="5,0,0,5" Style="{StaticResource EffectGrid}">
                        <Grid Width="185" Height="80" Background="WhiteSmoke">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="55" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Image Grid.Column="0" Source="{StaticResource iconCalendarDark}" />
                            <Grid Grid.Column="1">
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="25" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Label Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                                    Content="{Binding Name, FallbackValue=TxtProduct}"
                                                    FontSize="14" />
                                <Grid Grid.Row="1">
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="40" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <StackPanel Grid.Column="0">
                                        <Label Content="ID." Style="{StaticResource labels}" />
                                        <Label Content="Stock:" Style="{StaticResource labels}" />
                                        <Label Content="Precio:" Style="{StaticResource labels}" />
                                    </StackPanel>
                                    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Vertical">
                                        <Label Style="{StaticResource labels}" 
                                               Content="{Binding Id, StringFormat={}{0:c}, FallbackValue=0}"/>
                                        <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource txtbtns}" Text="{Binding 
                                                   Stock, StringFormat={}{0:#,#.00}, FallbackValue=0.00}" />
                                        <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource txtbtns}" Text="{Binding 
                                                   Price, StringFormat={}{0:c}, FallbackValue=$0.00}" />
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </Grid>
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

Mi deseo es que me orienten mejor para poder lograr esto.

Espero haber explicado bien mi problema y muchas gracias por su ayuda.